# I am trying to ensemble models to train the models and predict using VotingRegressor but i am getting an error please let me know what's the error

Tags: scikit-learn, ensemble-learning

**my code is as shown below**

```
from sklearn.ensemble import VotingRegressor 
from sklearn.svm import SVC
estimators=[('Randomregressor',RandomForestRegressor),('svc',SVC),('regressor_tree',DecisionTreeRegressor)]

ensemble=VotingRegressor(estimators=estimators,n_jobs=-1).fit(X_train,y_train)
```

*while ensembling three models i am getting an error as shown below*

---

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-169-b50113614234> in <module>()

----> 1 ensemble=VotingRegressor(estimators=estimators,weights=[2,1],n_jobs=-1).fit(X_train,y_train)
2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/ensemble/_base.py in _validate_estimators(self)
    247                 raise ValueError(
    248                     "The estimator {} should be a {}.".format(
--> 249                         est.__class__.__name__, is_estimator_type.__name__[3:]
    250                     )
    251                 )

ValueError: The estimator ABCMeta should be a regressor.
```

Comment: Problem is that SVC is a classifier not a regressor, use SVR instead.

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal, reproducible example of your code? (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) The data with X_train and y_train is missing. It also seems your code is incomplete, since there is no estimator "ABCMeta" in your provided code.